# Find certain value of numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]])
b = [0,1]
```

I want to find value of `a` that has `(0,1)` index which is 2 in this case.

I have tried `a[b]` but it does not show the expected result.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: first, that's not a numpy array, those are python lists. So, is your question about numpy array? (if yes, please modify the example) or is it about python lists? (if yes, please modify the question)

Comment: I have editted!

Answer (score 2):

Use `a[tuple(b)]`, like so:

```
In [3]: a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

In [4]: b=np.array([0,1])

In [5]: a[tuple(b)]
Out[5]: 2
```

For more info, see
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/user/basics.indexing.html#dealing-with-variable-numbers-of-indices-within-programs

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop also:-

```
a = np.array( [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = [0,1]

for var in b:
    a = a[var]
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [0,1]
```

These are lists, not ndarrays. Lists don't support fancy numpy indexing. To access the 1st element of the 0th entry of that list of lists, you'd use:

```
print(a[0][1])
```

If you actually want to use numpy ndarrays, try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print(a[0,1])
print(a[0][1])
```